# My sentence ended up having two adjacent “for”s. Is it grammatical?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, prepositional-verbs

I’m writing comments for my NGINX configuration and one of them got two adjacent “for”s. Should I avoid this construction, or is it just plain off? What would be better ways to phrase it?

> “Two seconds is a reasonable time to retain states for, for rate-limiting to work properly.”

> “Two seconds is a reasonable time to retain states for for rate-limiting to work properly.”

Comment: Just omit the first 'for'; it is unnecessary.

Comment: or rephrase slightly to *...is a reasonable time **for which** to retain states, for rate-limiting...* But note that in the *spoken* version most people wouldn't notice any repetition, since only the first instance of ***for*** would normally get enunciated with a "true" vowel. The second one would be just a neutral schwa, with minimal stress, so it would barely be noticed (even though technically speaking it's the *second* instance that's syntactically *required*, it can be very much "vocally underplayed").

Comment: There is a "rule" in English that you should not end a sentence(or clause) with a preposition. Usually this rule is completely unnecessary and can be ignored. But in situations like this you can see that rewording the sentence to comply with the rule (as @Fumble suggests) will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem wrong to me, only stylistically awkward. But I would prefer something smoother and more readily decipherable.

How about, "For rate-limiting to work properly, two seconds is a reasonable time to retain states for"?